# What is the easiest way to record gameplay on android?

Tags: motorola-moto-g3

I have a Moto g3. Is it possible to record android gameplay in the same way fraps records pc gameplay?

Answer (score 3):

Play Games provide a way to record gameplays. 
You can capture your gameplay in 720p or 480p, and choose to add video of yourself and commentary via your device's front facing camera and microphone.

**Steps**:

- Open the Play Games app.
- Select a game to open the game details page.
- At the top of the game details page, touch the record icon.
- Select your desired video quality setting. You can record in 480p SD or 720p HD.
- Based on your device's available storage space, you'll be shown  the maximum video length that you can record.
- Touch Launch to start your game. You'll see a floating video bubble appear with recording settings.
- Touch the record icon.
- After a 3-second countdown, your recording will begin.

Notes:
*To stop recording: Touch the floating video bubble, then the red stop icon Stop icon.
To dismiss recording: Drag the floating video bubble into the center of the screen. Drop the video bubble over the "X" to dismiss your recording.
Once you are finished recording, the video will save to your phone or tablet. You will also see an option to share your video online.*

Source: [Google support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6274965?hl=en)